# Is making a standalone header file for all the constant variables that many of your class may need a good practice?

Tags: c++

I am working with a game and I have constant variable like WIDTH and HEIGHT of the window. I wanted to make a Global.h file to put those constant variable so that if ever my class needs them I can just include the Global.h file and have access to the variable. Should I do this?

Just an example code to visualize what I meant:

Global.h

```cpp
#pragma once

const int WIDTH = 800;
const int HEIGHT = 600;
```

Class.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "Global.h"

class Class
{
private:
    int Multiply()
    {
        return WIDTH * HEIGHT;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example is not very good IMO. Things like window or screen dimensions should never be hard-coded, at least not since the old DOS days. Worst case the dimensions could be the minimum dimensions which are checked only once and doesn't need to be available to all source or header files.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude not sure I can follow what you meant :/

Comment: I have a 4K screen, with a resolution of 3840 by 2160 pixels. If your game opens a windows with the fixed dimensions of 800 by 600 pixels, it would be *very small*, less than a quarter of my screen area. And if I can't resize the window I will not play your game. That's why such dimensions should not be hard-coded. While it makes sense to have some constants globally available, some (like window dimensions) should not be global variables.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude im kind of new to programming and I havent figured out how to make my window adaptable to different screen sizes but anyway ill take this as a tip, thanks.

Comment: It is not a good idea. Eventually when the application grows, the file will be updated often and it will cause massive recompilation. Better to have multiple files each with related stuff so that common changes won’t cause a full recompilation if not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better practice is reducing the scope of all variables as much as possible. Ultimately reducing the pollution in the global space.

if the constants are only used in that class, keep it inside that class.

In the case where it makes sense to share a common constant value between all these classes, then having a common header file should be fine. But make sure the name is meaningful and hold consistent definitions between each usage.

You probably know this but, don't use globals just to be lazy. And document them properly I.e. Add appropriate comments next to the constants and why you chose the values may be.

Comment: No I will be actually using it in a lot of my class,. I am trying to reduce the times I will have to pass them through functions to use them because it will look messy.

If this is the case, should that be alright? Or should I just let it look messy

Comment: It's a little hard to answer without a concrete example. The example you gave is too generic to give a proper answer. So I just laid out some generic rules that might be good to consider.

Comment: my functions might get over 5+ parameters if I dont. Is that normal or am I doing it wrong

Comment: You can maybe pass a config struct into your classes with default values which initialize your parameters. it really depends on how you are planning to use it. Problem with constant global header is that it will be less flexible. Could you update your example to something closer to what you would like?

Comment: As long as it's not confidential information sure.

Comment: nvm it, I thought of something that would prevent me from doing this kind of work while trying to post my code here. Good answer though. Ill take note of this

Comment: Hopefully my answer was a little useful. My other tip would be, just get it working. Unless it's a big project and design could have heavy consequences, just get your hands dirty as soon as possible. if you realize that global constants dont work then redesign or update this question with your new problem. You might learn better from failures then just SO answers. All the best